# Qt Virtual Keyboard full screen

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu-16.04, qtvirtualkeyboard

I run Qt Virtual Keyboard example in **ubuntu**(16.04), it runs just on full screen mode and i can not see text edit when typing with virtual keyboard.
I want virtual keyboard width fit to window size and show under the text edit.
How ?

Answer (score 0):

I use this [component](https://github.com/githubuser0xFFFF/QtFreeVirtualKeyboard) for virtual keyboard, it works correctly.